# How to trace and profile all low level calls (c libraries) being used by a mod_perl or a mod_php application?

Tags: php, performance, perl, debugging, profiling

I've seen once on a site, a call graph digging into the most low level libraries of a web request initiated by a PHP appplication with call timings and summary. Seems to me that this is a great way to spot the reason of bottlenecks that aren't obvious while profiling PHP-only code.

Something like strace does but with far more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rasmus mentioned [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) a couple times in his presentations.  If I remember correctly it measures IO, memory, etc.  Might want to take a look.

Comment: Rasmus used valgrind in combination with callgrind and KCachegrind. Those tools can be used on any C based system, which includes Perl and mod_perl

Answer (score 1):

Tools like [VTune](http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/239144.htm) helps here. You can point this tool at a process or a system to profile and it will help find performance hotspots. VTune also has a call graph mode.